# How to invoke multiple LLM model in single chain or invoke multiple LLM model parallelly in Langchain?

Tags: fastapi, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, azure-openai

llm model invocation should be **parallel**

`chain1 = prompt | model | outputparser`

`chain2 = prompt2 | model2 | outputparser`